# Composing class behavior in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to develop some type of development pattern that makes possible to add methods to classes in a generic way. Almost like adding (behavioral) properties to classes and its attributes.

I want add methods that work with the internal data of a class ***independent of the name of the variable it is using***.

One possible way to doing so is by extending classes from others classes like the following example:

```
template <class Self,class Type>
class AcessOperator {
    const Type* data;
public:
    AcessOperator(const Type * data) : data(data){}
    Type & operator [](int index){
        return data[index];
    }
};

class Vector1 : public AcessOperator<Vector1,int>{
    int * any;
public:
    Vector1() : AcessOperator<Vector1,int>(any),any(0){
        any = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    }

    virtual ~Vector1(){ free(any); }
};
```

And I would have the operator[] for Vector1.

Another way is of reach such goal is by using macros:

```
#define access(class_type, pointer_name, index, return_type)\
return_type & operator[](int index){ \
    return pointer_name[index];\
}

class Vector2 {
    int * any;
public:
    Vector2() : any(0){
        any = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    }

    access(Vector2,any,index,int)

    virtual ~Vector2(){ free(any); }
};
```

I don't like macros, so I prefer the first way. However such approach results in a overhead in terms of data. I've printed the size of each class using the following code:

```
int main(){
    cout << sizeof(Vector1) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(Vector2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and this was the output:

```
sizeof(Vector1): 24
sizeof(Vector2): 16
```

It was the expected (my machine is 64 bits)

Vector1: 2 pointers + vtable pointer = 2*8 +8 = 24

Vector1: 1 pointer + vtable pointer = 8+8 = 16

Now here is the question:

Is it possible to reach this goal without *making classes fatter* and *without using macros*?

Comment: Why are you worried about 8 more bytes in a vector?  By the time you load up that vector with some meaningful data, aren't those eight bytes going to be inconsequential?

Comment: Your first code example is not correct: `operator []` can't return non-const reference to `data[...]` when `data` is declared as `const Type* data;`.

Comment: @Robert, i want add many more extensions to my class so size would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake. But still, this is just a example about the general idea of the problem. I didn't pay to much attention to code details. I will fix it when i get to the computer